# How to create a function/method which counts how may files are within a particular folder - T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help creating some kind of function/method to count how many files are in a particular folder. Here is an example sample data set I am using:

| FullPath | Type | Age (Years) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Computer\User01\MyDocuments\ | Folder | 4 |
| Computer\User01\MyDocuments\thisisafile.xlsx | File | 2.2 |
| Computer\User01\MyDocuments\anotherfile.doc | File | 1 |
| Computer\User01\MyDocuments\onemorefile.doc | File | 1.5 |
| Computer\User01\MyDocuments\secondfile.pptx | File | 1.6 |

As you can see from the sample data set, the folder: "Computer\User01\MyDocuments" contains 4 files. I could write the following code to show how many files are in this folder:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS No_of_files
 FROM SampleDataSet
 WHERE Type = 'File'
 AND FullPath LIKE 'Computer\User01\MyDocuments\%'
```

However, my data set contains hundreds of thousands of folders, all with a different number of files associated with them and therefore I can't specify the "FullPath" in the LIKE statement each time.

My desired output looks like this:

| FullPath | Type | No_of_files |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Computer\User01\MyDocuments\ | Folder | 1500 |
| Computer\User01\Pictures\ | Folder | 20 |
| Computer\User01\Desktop\ | Folder | 14 |
| Computer\User01\Downloads\ | Folder | 10 000 |

Does anyone know if this is possible and if there's an efficient way of doing this?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: All of your example folders are direct children of User01. Do you have sub folders below that level? If so how should they be treated?

Comment: If you are counting the number of files in the directory `Computer\User01\ ` should the files in `Computer\User01\MyDocuments\ `, `Computer\User01\Pictures\ `, etc all be included? or is it just the files in the root?

Comment: Yes I do. In my data I have a column for "DirectoryLevel" so I could restrict the folders shown to a particular directory level. If you know a way to account for sub-folders that would be beneficial but not necessary - thanks. @MartinSmith

Comment: So if you had a folder `Computer\User01\Downloads\Films\ ` and that had 30 files should the 30 be added to the count for   `Computer\User01\Downloads\ ` or ignored?

Comment: I guess I would like a function/method that would do a count of files from the folders I choose to display in the output if that makes sense @Larnu

Comment: Added to the count @MartinSmith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you could use a `JOIN` from the table onto itself to achieve this. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT D.FullPath,
       D.[Type],
       COUNT(F.FullPath) AS Files
FROM dbo.YourTable D
     LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable F ON F.FullPath LIKE D.FullPath + '%'
                              AND F.[Type] = 'File'
WHERE D.[Type] = 'Folder'
GROUP BY D.FullPath,
         D.[Type];
```

Comment: A correlated sub-query might be clearer than a `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Great! Thank you :-). Just a quick question, where would I put the code to only count the files above a certain age? e.g "[Age (Years)] >= 7"

Comment: In the `ON`, @AdamCraven .

Comment: Would you mind editing your code so i could see? Would be much appreciated - thanks! @Larnu

Comment: It would literally just go after the `AND F.[Type] = 'File'` and **prior** to the `WHERE`, @AdamCraven Just add `AND [Age (Years)] >= 7`